# Detect UIBezierPath collision ios

Tags: ios, ios8, uibezierpath

How can we detect if two UIBezierPath collide.
I have UIBezierPath A, that i draw line with in

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

method.

I have already another UIBezierPath B.

How can i detect if A while moving collide with B.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not keep an array containing UIBezierPath B points and when you start drawing UIBezierPath A, you can examine with

```
UIBezierPath containsPoint
```

instance method whether the point you are moving or adding to collide (equal) with already existing points in the UIBezierPath B's array?